# How to hide an item after fading it out (Objective-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation

I have the following if statement,

```
if (CGRectIntersectsRect(car.frame, car2.frame) && (upMovement = -1 ) && (car2.hidden == NO)){
    [self bounce];
    [self carexplode];
    if (car2used == NO) {
        addedScore = 1;
        car2Used = YES;
    }
    car2.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"car2flames.png"], nil];
    [car2 setAnimationRepeatCount:0];
    car2.animationDuration = 20;
    [car2 startAnimating];

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:4];
    [iceblock6 setAlpha:0];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    car2.hidden = YES;
```

Essentially, I want it to execute the top part of the method if one car crashes into it, then using UIView animations ^^, I want it to fade out, then be hidden, so that I can set hidden to no again when it reenters the view (after it exits the screen it reloads to the top of the screen). But with this, it just automatically is hidden, without the 4 second fade out animation. How can I fix this? I've tried putting car2.hidden in an if statement, but I don't know what to put in the condition because UIView isn't really bools or integers and all that. Anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:0.0 options:(UIViewAnimationOptions) animations:^{
        //place your animation here
        [iceblock6 setAlpha:0];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        //called when animation did finish. do what you want
        car2.hidden = YES;
    }];
```

Other way:

```
{
...
if (CGRectIntersectsRect(car.frame, car2.frame) && (upMovement = -1 ) && (car2.hidden == NO)){
    [self bounce];
    [self carexplode];
    if (car2used == NO) {
        addedScore = 1;
        car2Used = YES;
    }
    car2.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"car2flames.png"], nil];
    [car2 setAnimationRepeatCount:0];
    car2.animationDuration = 20;
    [car2 startAnimating];

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:4.0];
    [iceblock6 setAlpha:0];
    [UIView commitAnimations];

    [self performSelector:@selector(hideCar2) withObject:self afterDelay:4.0];
}

-(void)hideCar2
{
    car2.hidden = YES;
}
```

Comment: Hmm didn't seem to work unfortunately, still hid object right away. :(